# If normed space is infinite-dimensional then kernel is not trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, weak-topology

I am trying to understand the proof which gives weak closure of unit sphere is closed unit ball ($B$).

Let $x_0\in B$ and $G=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{x : |\ell_i (x-x_0)<\delta_i\}$ is any open weak neighborhood of $x_0$ where $\ell_i$s are continuous functionals and $\delta_i$s are positive real numbers.

Proof says: then there exists $0\neq y\in \bigcap_{i=1}^n Ker(\ell_i) $. I don't understand this part. I am not familiar with the notion codimension.

Any explanation in elementary level will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It may help to add detail on what hypotheses are on the space that $B$ and $G$ are sitting in (e.g. presumptively it is a topological vector space, but is there more?).  Given linear functionals $\ell_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$, it may help to consider the map $f$ from [your space] to $\mathbb{C}^n$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$) given by sending each $y$ in the space to the $n$-tuple of scalars $(\ell_1(y), \ell_2(y), \dots, \ell_n(y))$.  This is a linear map, and note that more or less by definition of $f$ one has $\ker(f) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker(\ell_i)$.

Comment: A vector subspace $V$ of a vector space $U\ne V$ is said to be of co-dimension $1$ if $U$ has a $1$-dimenxional vector subspace $W$ such that $V+W$ (the vector subspace generated by $V\cup W)$ is all of $U.$...If $U$ is a vector space over $\Bbb R$ and $\ell :U\to\Bbb R$ is linear and $\ell\ne 0$, let $V=\ell^{-1}\{0\}$ and choose  $u\in U$ with $\ell(u)\ne 0$ and let $W=\{ru:r\in\Bbb R\}.$

Answer (score 1):

I suppose we work in a space $X$ with infinite dimension. This question is about pure linear algebra. Nowhere is topology relevant.

The claim is that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker(\ell^i)\ne 0$. To see this, define the linear map
$$T: X \to\mathbb{K}^n: x \mapsto (\ell^1(x), \dots, \ell^n(x)).$$

Then $\ker(T) = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \ker(\ell^i).$ By the isomorphism theorem of vector spaces, we get an injective linear map
$$X/\ker(T) \to \mathbb{K}^n$$
and thus in particular $$\dim(X/\ker(T)) \le n.$$
If $\ker(T) = 0$, then the left hand side is $\dim(X) = \infty$, which is impossible. Hence, $\ker(T) \ne 0$. In fact, $\ker(T)$ has infinite dimension.